# Setting up Spring in Intellij Idea

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I want to set up a Spring project in IntelliJ Idea (Community Edition) and [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring.html) doesn't help, since Spring module doesn't appear. Is this possible?

Comment: https://patrickgrimard.io/2014/08/14/how-to-build-a-spring-boot-application-using-intellij-idea/

Comment: I am using 2017.2 version, which differs from tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the comparison chart here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

you can see that Spring support is Ultimate edition feature only.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA Community edition has no Spring support, you need IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. Please [check this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) for the differences between the editions.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear because you need to create it, the documentation is quite clear about it..

> You can add, remove or edit file sets in
>
> File | Project Structure | Modules |  | Spring
>
> or
>
> File | Project Structure | Facets | Spring ().

So you click the little green + sign and add a Spring facet/module

Comment: I've tried that before. But when I go and try to add (module or facet) Spring isn't there in frameworks. Just Kotlin, Android, Groovy, etc... Not Spring

Comment: check `File > Settings > Plugins` and add Spring